# Python Path Issue (Anaconda - Spyder)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, pythonpath

I have installed Anaconda and using Spyder Python.

I have installed latest Python and for some reason I can't use pip.

Searched the web and SoF and understood that this is something connected to the system path and env properties.

Here are my findings so far:

```
for p in sys.path: print(p)

C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python36.zip
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\DLLs
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions
C:\Users\user\.ipython

 os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-25-6e97a5381293>", line 1, in <module>
    os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None

KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

Please help me - what am I missing here? What path should I add?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that's strange. I would create `PYTHONPATH` variable containing only `;` and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Jean, say it again plz, what should I do?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "I can't use PIP"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sure: pip
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-365c9bfeb7d8>", line 1, in <module>
    pip

NameError: name 'pip' is not defined

Comment: @DinoAlessi no, add any additional details *to the question itself* not as a comment.

Comment: argh but you need to run the pip executable from `C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\scripts\pip` from a CMD console, not python console.

Comment: Wait, *are you trying to use pip* in a python interpreter *session*?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry, can you please write step by step how to do this I am a bit new to this

Comment: `pip` is a command which has to be run from the system console, not from the interpreter.

On windows, there's some added difficulty: `pip` isn't in the path. Given your error output you'd have to run `pip` as follows:

- open windows command prompt
- type: `C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\scripts\pip install whatevermodule` (args are an example)

Comment: I am trying to run pip in Anaconda's Spyder 3.6 lPython console - if I am wrong plz explain what is wrong?

Comment: @DinoAlessi you don't use PIP in a Python console, you use it in a terminal session, i.e. a `cmd` terminal in Windows

Comment: But basically, you should always give details about the *specific problem you are encountering*. This: "Searched the web and SoF and understood that this is something connected to the system path and env properties" was a red herring. This has nothing to do with your path variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot @juanpa.arrivillaga you all teached me what was my beginners issue - I like this site - top professionals!

Answer (score -1):

Anaconda has its own package manager , invoked with `conda install`.

Read about it here: https://conda.io/docs/using/pkgs.html

as to your case, your Environment variable PYTHONPATH needs to point to your python installation. Depending on what OS you are on, the steps will vary.

IIRC , the PYTHONPATH on ubuntu for example should be `/home/user/anaconda/bin/python`

EDIT: Looks like you're on windows, so you have to go through the system dialogue to setup an environment variable pointing to anaconda

EDIT 2: Make sure you're typing these on the terminal, as some of the comments here are suggesting. Anaconda should have a script in the installation directory to launch the "right terminal" so as to speak, but if you're on windows 10 then just searching conda or anaconda on the start menu *should* bring it up. This version of cmd has all the environments correctly loaded and setup.

Comment: aren't you mixing this up with `PYTHONHOME` ? and no, no env. variables are required to run python.

Comment: Isn't PYTHONPATH the one where python searches for all the modules to import? and usually no environment variables should be required, but I know installing on windows is kinda fucky. I'm just going by the trace

Comment: @S2C same - can't find conda:
conda install
  File "<ipython-input-31-3da4fdf131db>", line 1
    conda install
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


conda
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-32-7a5b6d2aa04e>", line 1, in <module>
    conda

NameError: name 'conda' is not defined

Comment: @DinoAlessi dude, these are suppose to be *terminal commands*, not Python code.

Comment: are you on cmd or are you on the anaconda form of cmd. I know anaconda for windows installs it's own terminal emulator which is what you have to use to run conda stuff. Also @juanpa.arrivillaga is right, these definitely are terminal commands.

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` is a colon/semicolon separated env variable (optional, should I say) used to locate the packages of python which aren't already in the distribution. Python can locate its root itself, no need for this.

Comment: Thanks to you all!!!! Understood thanks to @Jean-FrançoisFabre and S2C

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Agreed. I think juanpa is on the right track here where OP isn't typing into a terminal window. the bigger deal in windows is that the default cmd doesn't load the environment, the scripted setup in the anaconda/scripts folder does. setting the PYTHONPATH variable *should* also solve it, but is not ideal and launching the anconda terminal is a better option